# How to dereference multidimensional Array in C programming?

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, call, dereference

I want to pass a pointer to a multidimensional Array, so the value could be kept not copied. How can I do it? I also keep tracking the int count, will it work every time? The array that I need is memory. The struct has been declared before, outside the main.

```
struct registers
{
   int data;     
} registerX, registerY;

void first(int *counter, struct registers* X1, int **m)
{
  int value;
  printf("Enter the value for the X\n");
  scanf("%d", &value);
  X1->data = value;
  m[*counter][1] = X1->data;
  *counter = *counter++;

}
int main()
{
 int memory[SIZE][2];
 int count = 0;
 int choice;
 printf("Enter the instruction number:\n");

 while(choice != 107)
{
  scanf("%d", &choice);
  if(choice == 101)
  {
        memory[count][0] = 101;
        first(&count, &registerX, &memory[count][1]);
  }
```

Comment: `&memory[count][1]` is `int *`. receive `int *m`, then `m[*counter][1] = X1->data;` --> `*m = X1->data;`, `*counter = *counter++;` --> `++*counter;` or `*counter += 1;`

Comment: What is the difference between *counter++ and ++*counter?

Comment: `*counter++` meant `*(counter++)`. `++` for increment pointer. `++*counter` is increment `*counter` i.e. `(*counter)++`.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY except that  `++*counter` is **not** the same as `(*counter)++`.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant produce the results of the `*counter += 1`. I do not say to be the same.

Answer (score 2):

The function signature should be:

```
void first(int *counter, struct registers* X1, int m[][2])
```

Or equivalently:

```
void first(int *counter, struct registers* X1, int (*m)[2])
```

The call should be:

```
first(&count, &registerX, memory);
```

Comment: For the first one, will the values be saved? Because I need to print them at the end from main.

Comment: @AbylIkhsanov: the first and second declarations are *identical*. They're just different ways of spelling the exact same thing. In both cases the function parameter is a pointer to the first element of the array (which is an array of arrays, so the first element is itself an array).

Comment: I have changed my code by using your first example, now the problem is that array does not store any values, it keeps giving 0, at the line where :X1->data = value;
                      m[*counter][1] = X1->data;, X1->data stores the value but not the array, that is strange

Comment: @AbylIkhsanov: That is strange, and I'm inclined to believe that your problem lies elsewhere. Start over, make a *minimal* program that only exercises your array logic, and then build it up once you understand how each part works.

Answer (score 0):

- First of all, apart from what Kerrek SB said, you could replace

  ```
  *counter = *counter++;
  ```

  with this

  ```
  (*counter)++;
  ```

  **EDIT**: Sorry, I made a mistake trying to say what's wrong with *counter = *counter++, but I got some strange results with the sentence *pointer = *pointer++.
- Second, I see that you are using registerX while it's just a type, so you could first do this.

  ```
  registerX *rgx = NULL;
  rgx = malloc(sizeof(registerX));
  ```

  and use.

  ```
  first(&count, rgx, memory);
  ```

Considering what I said above, this code worked for me.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZE 5

typedef struct registers {
    int data;     
} registerX, registerY;

void first(int *counter, struct registers *X1, int m[][2]) {
    int value;

    printf("Enter the value for the X: ");
    scanf("%d", &value);

    X1->data = value;
    m[*counter][1] = X1->data;

    (*counter)++;

    return ;
}

int main() {
    int memory[SIZE][2];
    int count = 0;
    int choice;

    registerX *rgx = NULL;
    rgx = malloc(sizeof(registerX));

    printf("Enter the instruction number: ");

    while(choice != 107) {
        scanf("%d", &choice);

        if (choice == 101) {
            memory[count][0] = 101;
            first(&count, rgx, memory);
            printf("Number %d was stored in memory[%d][%d]\n\n", memory[count-1][1], count-1, 1);
        }

        printf("Enter more instructions: ");
    }

    return 0;
}
```